# How to access two controls in single row of listview witch button in the same row

Tags: xamarin-forms-4

I want to change isEditable in each single row using togglebutton. When togglebutton is pressed Datepicker and entry are edited and when when togglebutton is unchechecked they are not edited.
[image]
I just want to change state of datePicker and Entry with togglebutton from is enabled false to enabled true and the way around. But I can't access them using x:Name. Like they are invisible inside the listview